# keycloak on openshift jar deployments

Tags: jar, openshift, keycloak

I've installed keycloak on openshift environment.

I've to deploy a custom user storage SPI. In a non-container environment I will copy the jar in the deployments directory, in openshift environment how could load the jar file?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create two volume Mounts for storing 1) this custom jars in the server and 2) for creating the start up script
   some thing like this

   volumeMounts:
   - name: volume-jboss-startup-scripts
   mountPath: /opt/jboss/startup-scripts
   - name: volume-keycloak-custom-requiredactions
   mountPath: /opt/jboss/custom-requiredactions
   readOnly: true
2. You could use secret to create the JAR file
3. Map the volume to the above secret (your file will be placed in the PATH now)
   some thing like this

   volumes:
   - name: volume-jboss-startup-scripts
   configMap:
   name: keycloak-10-jboss-startup-scripts
   - name: volume-keycloak-custom-requiredactions
   secret:
   secretName: keycloak-custom-requiredaction
4. You need to write start up script
   script will have copy command
   CP (copy ) cp /custom.jar /opt/keycloak/standalone/deployments
   add that in configMap with name "keycloak-10-jboss-startup-scripts"
   So basically you are creating a file and a startup script in the server , when we reload the deploymentconfig , it will run  the script which copies the necessary jar file into deployments ,
   ENJOY
   Sorry for the formatting in the message
   NOTE:- You could use any names for configmap or the secret or you could use just configmap to get the startup script and the jar file into server